# How do I retrieve all objects within an array in a mongodb collection

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, blazor, loaddata

:) I'm new to mongoDB and i've been given instructions to use an already existing database to a new .NET application. (Blazor)

The database consists of tests made on hardware to get results like:
Temperature, date, warnings etc.

So the structure of the test collection looks something like this:

```
_id: ObjectId("1239082fasd09asd")  
test_name: "hw_cold-batch-04"  
devices: Array   
events: Array
```

the events array contains 100k+ objects that have the following structure:

```
device_id: "553AD00"  
date: "2020-11-16 12:48:30"  
temperature: -25.123  
iteration: 5044 //(This starts from 1 and ends att somewhere along 100k+)  
result_str: "0:01:33"
```

**How would I query this to get ALL events from a specific test_name for example?**

I've got it to work by getting ALL data from the collection to the application and then use conditions to get specific data through c#. But the thing is that it takes about 1 minute until the data has loaded.
And I've read that indexing would possibly solve this, but to create a index I need to start using specific queries first I guess?

Or do you have any other suggestions on how to load data faster from mongodb to .net web application?

Comment: You generally query using the [db.collection.find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#find-documents-that-match-query-criteria) that match a query criteria.

Comment: @prasad_ Yes, sorry if I was unclear. I've tried different queries already but I can't figure out how to properly write it.

I did try stuff like: 
db.users.find({events: {$elemMatch: {test_name:"553AD00",device_id: "553AD00" }}}) but I can't get it to work. How would you write it?

Comment: What are you trying to query?   Can you post a sample query criteria and expected result.

Comment: Well, since I'm new to this I don't really know if I'm thinking in the right way. But basically what I want is this:

I want to be able to get all the objects that are stored in the event-array if the test_name matches whatever I put in. 

In c# we did something like this:  
`foreach(event in test.events)
{
   if(test_name == "bat-cold-3")
{
     //store it in a list to display later
}
}`

Comment: `db.collection.find( { test_name: "bat-cold-3" }, { _id: 0, events: 1 } )`.  This will return matching documents with one _array_ field, `events`. A `collection.find()` method always returns a [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#iterate-the-returned-cursor), and you can iterate this cursor _or_ apply cursor methods.

Comment: @prasad_ Thank you! That was what I was looking for. Didn't work in MongoDB compass as I thought but in mongo shell it worked perfect. I really appriciate your help.